# Load data from json in database + Call to undefined method error + Zend Framework

Tags: php, sql, json, zend-framework, methods

I want to load the data from 2 json files in my database.
The markup of json-file 1:

```
{
    "wijken": {
        "11": {
            "coords": "3.79073170001967,51.1717753664505,0 3.79020920176376,51.1723018883706,0 3.78989543642226,51.1729670713336,0 3.78983091856725,51.1736482209016,0 3.79035112720225,51.174896701853,0 3.79089521566258,51.1755715564749",
            "id": "kml_1",
            "fid": "0",
            "wijziging": "Ja",
            "nieuwnr": "11",
            "naam": "Noordoost",
            "wijk": "Kanaaldorpen en -zone",
            "wijknr": "11",
            "objectid": "1",
            "area": "0",
            "len": "0"
        },
        "12": {
            "coords": "3.78365655007178,51.0788871010895,0 3.78236442099369,51.078059164252,0 3.78145483809257,51.0772221613719,0 3.77888089082956,51.0750304363252,0 3.77670256394985,51.0734391195385,0 3.77279418332369,51.0714074143415",
            "id": "kml_2",
            "fid": "1",
            "wijziging": "Ja",
            "nieuwnr": "12",
            "naam": "Noordoost",
            "wijk": "Oostakker",
            "wijknr": "12",
            "objectid": "2",
            "area": "0",
            "len": "0"
        },
        "14": {
            "coords": "3.75380711028508,51.0773171406482,0 3.75436966210847,51.0771805986634,0 3.75572764083826,51.077128950619,0 3.75568978579317,51.0768781807292,0 3.75764106686573,51.0767833829573,0 3.75931252603489,51.0764226285855",
            "id": "kml_3",
            "fid": "2",
            "wijziging": "Ja",
            "nieuwnr": "14",
            "naam": "Noordoost",
            "wijk": "Sint Amandsberg",
            "wijknr": "14",
            "objectid": "3",
            "area": "0",
            "len": "0"
        },
        ......
}
```

The markup of json-file 2:

```
{
    "geboortes": [
        {
            "wijk": "Binnenstad",
            "year_1999": 167,
            "year_2000": 156,
            "year_2001": 167,
            "year_2002": 179,
            "year_2003": 150,
            "year_2004": 196,
            "year_2005": 187,
            "year_2006": 204,
            "year_2007": 189,
            "year_2008": 206,
            "year_2009": 218
        },
        {
            "wijk": "Bloemekenswijk",
            "year_1999": 106,
            "year_2000": 105,
            "year_2001": 106,
            "year_2002": 101,
            "year_2003": 125,
            "year_2004": 133,
            "year_2005": 138,
            "year_2006": 138,
            "year_2007": 120,
            "year_2008": 177,
            "year_2009": 143
        },
        {
            "wijk": "Brugse Poort - Rooigem",
            "year_1999": 231,
            "year_2000": 219,
            "year_2001": 198,
            "year_2002": 205,
            "year_2003": 207,
            "year_2004": 206,
            "year_2005": 256,
            "year_2006": 277,
            "year_2007": 258,
            "year_2008": 298,
            "year_2009": 295
        },
        .....
}
```

My two tables:

> - "Districts" with fields (= fields of the json): coords, id, fid, wijziging, nieuwnr, naam, wijk, wijknr, objectid, area, len
> - "Births" with fields (= fields of the json): wijk, year_1999, year_2000, year_2001, year_2002, year_2003, year_2004, year_2005,
>     year_2006, year_2007, year_2008, year_2009

I have an updateAction where I load the data from the 2 jsons in the 2 tables :

```
public function updateAction()
    {

        $view = $this->view;
        $view->title = $this->_translate->_('Edit') . ' - ' . $this->_translate->_('Back office');


        $url = "http://data.appsforghent.be/poi/wijken.json";
        $url2 = "http://data.appsforghent.be/demografie/geboortes.json";
        $url3 = "http://data.appsforghent.be/demografie/overlijdens.json";

        $json = file_get_contents($url);
        $json2 = file_get_contents($url2);

        $out = Zend_Json::decode($json);
        $out2 = Zend_Json::decode($json2);

        // WIJKEN JSON
        foreach($out["wijken"] as $w) 
    {           
            $coords = addslashes($w['coords']);
            $id = addslashes($w['id']);
            $fid = addslashes($w['fid']);
            $wijziging = addslashes($w['wijziging']);
            $nieuwnr = addslashes($w['nieuwnr']);
            $naam = addslashes($w['naam']);
            $wijk = addslashes($w['wijk']);
            $wijknr = addslashes($w['wijknr']);
            $objectid = addslashes($w['objectid']);
            $area = addslashes($w['area']);
            $len = addslashes($w['len']);

        $data = array('coords'  => $coords,
                      'id' => $id,
                      'fid'      => $fid,
                      'wijziging'   => $wijziging,
                      'nieuwnr'   => $nieuwnr,
                      'naam'   => $naam,
                      'wijk'   => $wijk,
                      'wijknr'   => $wijknr,
                      'objectid'   => $objectid,
                      'area'   => $area,
                      'len'   => $len,      
        );

        $district = new Backoffice_Model_District($data);

        $districtMapper = new Backoffice_Model_DistrictMapper();
        $districtMapper->save($district);

        }

        // GEBOORTES JSON
        foreach($out2["geboortes"] as $g) 
    {           
            $wijk = addslashes($g['wijk']);
            $year_1999 = addslashes($g['year_1999']);
            $year_2000 = addslashes($g['year_2000']);
            $year_2001 = addslashes($g['year_2001']);
            $year_2002 = addslashes($g['year_2002']);
            $year_2003 = addslashes($g['year_2003']);
            $year_2004 = addslashes($g['year_2004']);
            $year_2005 = addslashes($g['year_2005']);
            $year_2006 = addslashes($g['year_2006']);
            $year_2007 = addslashes($g['year_2007']);
            $year_2008 = addslashes($g['year_2008']);
            $year_2009 = addslashes($g['year_2009']);

        $data2 = array('wijk'        => $wijk,
                      'year_1999'   => $year_1999,
                      'year_2000'   => $year_2000,
                      'year_2001'   => $year_2001,
                      'year_2002'   => $year_2002,
                      'year_2003'   => $year_2003,
                      'year_2004'   => $year_2004,
                      'year_2005'   => $year_2005,
                      'year_2006'   => $year_2006,
                      'year_2007'   => $year_2007,
                      'year_2008'   => $year_2008,
                      'year_2009'   => $year_2009,

        );

        $birth = new Backoffice_Model_Birth($data2);

        $birthMapper = new Backoffice_Model_BirthMapper();
        $birthMapper->save($birth);

        }

        echo "Worked!";

    }
```

save function in my DistrictMapper: (same for BirthMapper but different values)

```
public function save(Backoffice_Model_District $district)
    {


        $data = array('coords'   => $district->getCoords(),
                      'id'       => $district->getId(),
                      'fid'      => $district->getFid(),
                      'wijziging'=> $district->getWijziging(),
                      'nieuwnr'  => $district->getNieuwnr(),
                      'naam'     => $district->getNaam(),
                      'wijk'     => $district->getWijk(),
                      'wijknr'   => $district->getWijknr(),
                      'objectid' => $district->getObjectid(),
                      'area'     => $district->getArea(),
                      'len'      => $district->getLen(),
        );
```

He loads the data from json to table1 but when he wants to load json2 to table 2 I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Backoffice_Model_Birth::setYear_1999() in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/StaGent/library/Ahs/Model/Abstract.php on
>   line 40

My Abstract.php

```
abstract class Ahs_Model_Abstract
{
    /**
     * @param array $values
     */
    public function __construct(array $values) {
        foreach($values as $key => $value) {
            $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($key);
            $this->{$setter}($value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post the contents of Applications/MAMP/htdocs/StaGent/library/Ahs/Model/Abstract.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left the underscore out of my variables and now it works!